# How can I enable Workflow & Approvals on my Salesforce site?

Tags: workflow, salesforce

I am trying to add a workflow to my Salesforce app and following the Cookbook tutorial I get that there should be an option under Create in the menu with the title Workflow & Approvals, but I don't have this option. What can I do? I read that Workflows have to be enabled, but I can't find where to do this.

Anyone with experience?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Not all editions of Salesforce have workflow available, you need either Enterprise or Unlimited](http://www.salesforce.com/crm/editions-pricing.jsp?d=70130000000rynQ&internal=true) — what version are you using? If you're using a developer org there should be no problem as that has everything available for you to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Workflow rules only work for those that have the proper version of salesforce that supports workflow.  As a small business with 20 user licenses it isnt very cost effective for us yet to implement the more expensive edition of salesforce to support workflow which is about $100 a person more per month.